# Can anyone tell how can I get this done: code of relation of array with pointers

Tags: arrays, c, initialization, declaration, variable-length-array

```
#include<stdio.h>
    
int main(void){
    const int size=5;
    int grades[size]={34,23,67,89,68};
    double sum=0.0;
    double *ptr_to_sum=&sum;
    int i;
    printf("\n my grades are:\n");
    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        printf("%d\t",grades[i]);}
        printf("\n\n");
        for(i=0;i<size;i++){
            sum+=grades[i];
        }
        printf("my average grade is %.2f\n\n",sum/size);
        printf("\n\n");
        printf("sum is at %p, or %luandis%lf\n",ptr_to_sum,ptr_to_sum,*ptr_to_sum);
        printf("grades are at %lu to %lu\n",grades,grades+5);
    }
```

Even though being a simple code , I am unable to figure out the error ,the code is correct but I just don't know why this error is coming.
Please can anyone help me in this?
What I can just pretend after much thinking is that it is occurring due to the datatype long that is being used for the sum.

```
ERROR:pointers.c: In function 'main':
pointers.c:7:5: error: variable-sized object may not be initialized
    7 |     int grades[size]={34,23,67,89,68};
      |     ^~~
pointers.c:7:23: warning: excess elements in array initializer
    7 |     int grades[size]={34,23,67,89,68};
      |                       ^~
pointers.c:7:23: note: (near initialization for 'grades')    
pointers.c:7:26: warning: excess elements in array initializer
    7 |     int grades[size]={34,23,67,89,68};
      |                          ^~
pointers.c:7:26: note: (near initialization for 'grades')    
pointers.c:7:29: warning: excess elements in array initializer
    7 |     int grades[size]={34,23,67,89,68};
      |                             ^~
pointers.c:7:29: note: (near initialization for 'grades')    
pointers.c:7:32: warning: excess elements in array initializer
    7 |     int grades[size]={34,23,67,89,68};
      |                                ^~
pointers.c:7:32: note: (near initialization for 'grades')    
pointers.c:7:35: warning: excess elements in array initializer
    7 |     int grades[size]={34,23,67,89,68};
      |                                   ^~
pointers.c:7:35: note: (near initialization for 'grades')
```

Comment: You're using a constant value of `5`. So what about `enum { size = 5 };`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the C Standard (6.7.6.2 Array declarators):

> 4. ... If the size is an **integer constant expression** and the element type
>    has a  known constant size, the array type is not a
>    variable  length array type;  otherwise, the array type is a variable
>    length array type.

and (6.6 Constant expressions)

> 6 **An integer constant expression** shall have integer type and shall
> only have operands that are integer constants, enumeration constants,
> character constants, sizeof expressions whose results are integer
> constants, and floating constants that are the immediate operands of
> casts. Cast operators in an integer constant expression shall only
> convert arithmetic types to integer types, except as part of an
> operand to the sizeof operator.

That is in these declarations

```
const int size=5;
int grades[size]={34,23,67,89,68};
```

the variable `size` is not an integer constant expression. Thus the array `grades` is a variable length array. And according to the C Standard (6.7.9 Initialization)

> 3 The type of the entity to be initialized shall be an array of
> unknown size or a complete object type **that is not a variable length
> array type**.

So you may mot initialize the array `grades` when it is declared as a variable length array.

Instead of the constant variable `size` you could use an integer constant expression as for example an enumeration constant:

```
enum {  size = 5 };
int grades[size]={34,23,67,89,68};
```

Pay attention to that as you already have the integer constant `size` then instead of the magic number `5` in this statement

```
printf("grades are at %lu to %lu\n",grades,grades+5);
```

it will be better to write

```
printf( "grades are at %p to %p\n", 
        ( void * )grades, ( void * )( grades + size ) );
```

To output pointers you have to use the conversion specifier `%p`.

Another approach is to declare the array `grades` without specifying the number of elements. For example

```
int grades[] = { 34, 23, 67, 89, 68 };
```

and then to declare a variable that stores the number of elements in the array like

```
const size_t size = sizeof( grades ) / sizeof( *grades );
```

Answer (score 1):

In C, if you use a variable as a dimension of an array, even a `const` variable, it makes the array variable-sized (In C++, that is not the case for `const` variables).

Because the array is variable-sized (from the compiler's perspective), it can not initialize the array - because it assumes it doesn't know how many elements are there, so it can not generate proper initialization code.

You will have to resort to macros here, I am afraid - if you want to give the array a size. Alternatively, you can omit the size, and allow the compiler to deduce the size for you - but this would require you to initialize **all** elements of the array, which would not be necessary if you give the array a size.

Comment: Thanks to all for helping me so much. I got it now. Kudos to you all.

Answer (score 0):

The complaint is that you have both a size, given by a variable (so it's not constant), and a list of initializers.  Here:

```
const int size=5;
int grades[size]={34,23,67,89,68};
```

Try this instead:

```
int grades[] = {34,23,67,89,68};
```

If you really need the size as a variable/constant, either of these will work:

```
#define NUM_GRADES 5
int grades[] = {34,23,67,89,68};

...

for(i=0;i<NUM_GRADES;i++){
```

-- OR --

```
int grades[] = {34,23,67,89,68};
int size = sizeof grades / sizeof grades[0];
```